# Is there a determinant for linear maps between not necessarily finite-dim vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Two main definitions of the determinants from what I understand is the product of the eigenvalues $\prod_{j=1}^n \lambda _j$ and the signed area of the unit cube after the linear transformation is applied. Neither of these definitions really generalize to infinite dimensional vector spaces, such as $A:L^2([-1,1])\rightarrow L^2([-1,1])$.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_determinant

Comment: Some references here might help:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347474/how-can-one-define-a-kind-of-determinant-on-reduced-group-c-algebra/348240#348240